# How do you connect a coax cable to a homemade bi-quad antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna

I want to build antennas because I think they're pretty cool. Like invisible photons that pass through matter. But I'm struggling with basics and considering removing my tinfoil hat very soon.

Here is the not working antenna I built: https://buildyourownantenna.blogspot.com/2014/07/double-biquad-antenna-calculator.html

Does the shield need to contact the reflector ? 
Is the reflector connected to something ?
Does the antenna element (the 4 squares) connects the shield and the coax inner cable ? How could it radiate then if it's a closed circuit ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Note: a closed circuit will radiate, especially if the enclosed loop area is large enough in relation to the wavelength of the transmit frequency, due to the loop(s) generating changing magnetic fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it clear from all of the diagrams and photographs?

The two conductors at the very center of the biquad wire are connected to the center pin and shield of the coax connector. The reflector is also connected to the shield.